# Some problems with printing on my Ender 3

Tags: creality-ender-3, print-quality

This week I got an Ender 3. When printing the models, I get some inaccuracies on them. I tried printing a low-polygon chess rook, and it isn't printed accurately. It has these additional plastic printed that shouldn't be there:

[image]

It also isn't symmetrical:

[image]

On the top there should be 4 identical cuboids, but on the 2 of them there isn't plastic inside and also they are slightly wider:

[image]

This is the STL file and also the G-code file sliced by Ultimaker Cura: [files](https://gofile.io/d/LpoP3f)

My specifications:

- printer: Ender 3 (nothing is modded, no parts have been changed)
- slicing software: Ultimaker Cura
- slicing settings:

  - layer height: 0.12 mm
  - printing speed: 30 mm/s

    - initial layer printing speed: 20 mm/s
  - brim adhesion
  - quality: 0.16 mm
  - fan speed: 100%

I have properly calibrated the Esteps/mm and I have levelled the bed correctly.

I would really appreciate your help, I'm new to the 3D printing world.

---

To follow up advice from comments, I've tightened the X-axis belt and printed the calibration cube, I think now it should be good:

[image] I'll print the rook model once more and maybe the symmetry will be good now.

Comment: have you tried running an alignment check. https://www.matterhackers.com/articles/top-ten-prints-to-calibrate-your-3d-printer

Comment: @VarunW. I haven't done these tests. Should I try doing all of them, or are there any specific ones for the problems I mentioned? Thank you.

Comment: I would try one and see which axis the problem occurs at then just timer that axis until it works.

Comment: Seems like eiterh X or Y is off - please show us a cube that has alignment marks on it, such as one that has X Y Z on the respective surfaces.

Comment: @Trish I've tightened the X belt and printed the calibration cube. Since I can't post images in the comments I've edited the question. Is the calibration cube looking good? Thank you!

Comment: The initial rook showed the clear signs of improperly tensioned belts. It is understandable to include that part into the question, but, it is part of the solution. Please remember SE sites are different than traditional forums, here we ask questions which are answered by the community or yourself through help of the comments to request additional information. Please take the [tour] and visit [help]! If belt tension is the final conclusion, please remove the part under the line in your question and put that in an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @0scar thank you, I've applied your edit. I will print the model once more tomorrow and if the belt tightening is the solution, I will post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

So I've been trying to fix that problem and I've managed to do it. I have tightened the X axis belt and went through all configuration files on https://teachingtechyt.github.io, that fixed my problem. Thank you for helping me to solve this issue.